# Gave my full name, age, office address and mobile number to a probable scammer

Tags: scams, identity-theft

What's the worst that can happen if I have given my name, office address, age and mobile number to a person who was most probably a scammer?

I'm still not sure, it was scam, because emails were very well written without any spelling mistakes, he provided legal documents and proofs for everything he said. I. After more investigation, I've started realizing that it was a scam.I 'm considering myself a big fool for sharing this information with him.

I ended the conversation in a nice way, didn't let him know that I'm doubting his credibility.

What can I face as a result of sharing the information that I mentioned?